# Wikimedia Commons: See all images over a certain size, within a category

Tags: wikimedia-commons

Within the [Berlin category on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aBerlin), I want to see all images with width > 2100 pixels.

Is there a way to get this?

Bonus if thumbnails are shown, so that I can efficiently choose a picture I like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort by size in catscan (by Magnus Manske, the creator of MediaWiki): http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php

[Berlin images sorted by size](http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php?language=commons&project=wikimedia&categories=Berlin&ns%5B6%5D=1&sortby=filesize&sortorder=descending&ext_image_data=1&doit=1); or, more useful category, [Quality images of Berlin sorted by size](http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php?language=commons&project=wikimedia&categories=Quality_images_of_Berlin&ns%5B6%5D=1&sortby=filesize&sortorder=descending&ext_image_data=1&doit=1). You can't filter by width, but file size is a good approximation, there's a width column and you can pick the appropriate category. Walking subcategories is unreliable due to how MediaWiki categories are made but [you can try](http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php?language=commons&project=wikimedia&depth=1&categories=Berlin&ns%5B6%5D=1&sortby=filesize&sortorder=descending&doit=1) (look at the bottom after all the errors). You can also produce a gallery which you'd then need to preview on a Commons page; and there are other tools/versions which produce thumbs but have less filtering/sorting options.

Comment: My attempts fail with `Unknown MySQL server host 'commons.labsdb'`... would you be kind enough to provide the request itself? There is a convenient `Link to a pre-filled form for the query you just ran` (preferably without autorun). Thanks!

Comment: Added above, the tool had some problems.

Comment: Looks like PetScan (the new CatScan) no longer supports this functionality.